# Calculating a very long number in C programming

Tags: c, integer

How to implement a program in c to calculate 2^999 ?

Comment: Look for a [bignum library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries).

Comment: You don't need to write a program for that, the result is 5.35754304 × 10 in 300. Done.

Comment: @VladLazarenko - How you reached to that conclusion?

Comment: If you're just looking for the answer: `5357543035931336604742125245300009052807024058527668037218751941851755255624680612465991894078479290637973364587765734125935726428461570217992288787349287401967283887412115492710537302531185570938977091076523237491790970633699383779582771973038531457285598238843271083830214915826312193418602834034688` (fits under 500 characters)

Comment: @Mysticial - Can i calculate it without using Big Int Libraries.

Comment: Yes you can, but it isn't too different from writing a simple bignum library from scratch.

Comment: @Mysticial - Suppose we are not allowed to use bignum , neither we have time to create one from scratch. Isn't there any mathematical trick to shorten this , some array technique or maybe string which can solve this problem.Without actually calculating it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a big integer library which work with arbitrarily sized arrays. GMP is popular: http://gmplib.org/.

If you're willing to sacrifice precision you can use a `double` which can represent values up to about 1.8 * 10^308 by just using `pow()` (2^999 = ~5.4 * 10^300).

Comment: @Dampsquid: What are you talking about... the GMP documentation is perfectly serviceable, and it's a good library...

Comment: I'm sure it is, I meant I hope I never have to do calculation to that level of significant digits, doubles surfice for me.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <math.h>

double a = pow(2, 999);
```

Comment: ...subject to an appropriate implementation of C :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%.0f\n", 0x1p999);
```

Oops, too short so adding some random text..

Answer (score 2):

`bc` has a bignum library built into it and is on every unix-compatible system worthy of the name.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    FILE *p;

    p=popen("bc","w");
    fprintf(p, "2^999\n");
    fflush(p);
    fclose(p);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Holy cow, dude.. Really? Why not write a shell script then?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void mul2(char *n){
    int c = 0;
    while(*n){
        int v;
        v  = c + (*n - '0') * 2;
        c  = v / 10;
        *n++ = v % 10 + '0';
    }
    if(c) *n++ = c + '0';
    *n = '\0';
}

void print(char *n){
    strrev(n);
    printf("%s\n", n);
}

int main (void){
    char num[302] = "1";
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<999;i++)
        mul2(num);
    print(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 302 : (((log10 2)*999 ) roundup is 301) + 1(for '\0')